# undefined is not an object( evaluating '_reactNative.ViewPropTypes.style')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Description** ---
When i clone a project from github, after `npm install react-native run-ios`,the following error occurs: **undefined is not an object( evaluating '_reactNative.ViewPropTypes.style')**

[image: Here is the error screenshot]

**Additional Information**

1. react-native-cli: 2.0.1
2. react-native: 0.44

My homepage for code-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { Container, Header, Title, Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon } from 'native-base';

import Button1 from './Button';
import StreamStripContainer from '../containers/StreamStripContainer';
import StreamElementsContainer from '../containers/StreamElementsContainer';

class Stream extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5'}} >
          <Header>
              <Left>
                  <Button transparent>
                      <Icon name='menu' />
                  </Button>
              </Left>
              <Body>
                  <Title>Stream</Title>
              </Body>
              <Right>
                  <Button transparent>
                      <Icon name='search' />
                  </Button>
              </Right>
          </Header>
          <StreamStripContainer />
          <StreamElementsContainer />
          {/* <Button1 onPress={Actions.content} title='Go To Next Scene' /> */}
        </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5'
  }
});

export default Stream;
```

Comment: This is pretty impossible to help with without more information about the code you are trying to run.

Comment: What information u will need?

Comment: what code are you trying to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved error by updating native-base to 2.1.4 as my react native version was 0.44

View.propTypes is deprecated and instead ViewPropTypes is used from RN44, which is introduced in the latest version of NativeBase as well. So For RN44 go for NativeBase v2.1.4 and anything below RN44, you can use NB v2.1.3

Answer (score -2):

That is the issue with react-native-router-flux, your version of react-native is not compatible with the version of react-native-router-flux.
Upgrade your version of react-native-router-flux.
[This](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/851) might help.